# I am new to Multithreading. Trying to access and print value of static var "i" from two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Multithreading. Can someone help me why "11" is printing from Thread 1 (i.e. second thread)? I'm trying to print value of i as:
from 1 to 4 && 8 to 10 by first thread.
from 5 to 7 by second thread.

How can I get that? Any help appreciated.

```
public class ThreadClassOS {
    static int i=1;
    void print2()
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (i <= 10) {
                if ((i > 0 && i < 5) || (i > 7 && i < 11)) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                i++;
                notify();
            }
        }
    }
    void print1()
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (i <= 10)
            {
                if (i > 4 && i < 8) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(i + " "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                i++;
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadClassOS os = new ThreadClassOS();
        Runnable r1= os::print1;
        Thread t1= new Thread(r1);

        Runnable r2= os::print2;
        Thread t2= new Thread(r2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

O/P:

```
1 Thread-0
2 Thread-0
3 Thread-0
4 Thread-0
5 Thread-1
6 Thread-1
7 Thread-1
8 Thread-0
9 Thread-0
10 Thread-0
11 Thread-1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh3AX.png)

Answer (score 1):

After `Thread-1` prints 7, he waits **inside the while loop**, then `Thread-0` prints `8,9,10` and before notify `Thread-1` to wake up,`Thread-0` increase `i` again, Hence `i = 11` at this moment.

Now when `Thead-1`, which already **inside the while loop**,  gets the notify, he prints out the value of `i` which we know that `i = 11`.

Comment: But since print statement is under while loop, when i comes to 11, while loop should not be executed, I think.

Comment: @AkashKumarSingh No. The while condition is only checked every time you start an iteration.

Comment: Thread-0 passed the condition while i was equal to 7, while Thread-0 was sleeping, i has changed, but the condition was already checked. When thread is waking up, he continues the next line.

Comment: I guess your answer has confusion between Thread 0  and 1, as I can see in O/P Thread 1 prints 7 and then Thread 0 prints from 8 to 10.

Comment: @AkashKumarSingh sorry for the inconvenience.. i just updated my answer. please mark as answer if it is satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some simple printouts clarifies the sequence of events:

```
public class ThreadClassOS {

    static int i=1;

    void print0()  {

        synchronized (this) {

            while (i <= 10)   {

                if (i > 4 && i < 8) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(i + " "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                i++;
                if(i==11) {
                    System.out.println("i incremented to 11 by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    void print1()  {
        synchronized (this) {

            while (i <= 10) {

                if (i > 0 && i < 5 || i > 7 && i < 11) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("i="+ i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is waiting");
                        wait();
                        System.out.println("i="+ i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " stop waiting");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                i++;
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadClassOS os = new ThreadClassOS();
        Runnable r0= os::print0;
        Thread t0= new Thread(r0);

        Runnable r1= os::print1;
        Thread t1= new Thread(r1);

        t0.start();
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1 Thread-0 
> 2 Thread-0  
> 3 Thread-0  
> 4 Thread-0  
> 5 Thread-1  
> 6 Thread-1  
> 7 Thread-1  
> i=8 Thread-1 is waiting  
> 8 Thread-0  
> 9 Thread-0  
> 10 Thread-0  
> i incremented to 11 by Thread-0  
> i=11 Thread-1 stop waiting  
> 11 Thread-1